# Is $\int f \,\mathrm{d}\nu$ Gaussian if $f$ is a Gaussian process and $\nu$ is a regular bounded finitely additive measure?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

Let $T$ be a metric space and denote by $C_b(T,\mathbb{R})$ the space of bounded real-valued continuous functions on $T$. Suppose that $f$ is a continuous bounded Gaussian process, that is, $(f_t)_{t\in T}$ is a family of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ such that
\begin{align*}
(\text{i})& \,\,\forall \omega\in \Omega\colon \left[ t\mapsto f_t(\omega)\right] \in C_b(T,\mathbb{R}),\\[2pt]
(\text{ii})& \,\,\forall t_1,\ldots,t_m\in T\colon (f_{t_1},\ldots,f_{t_m}) \text{ is a Gaussian random vector}.
\end{align*}
Now as I found in [this](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/dual-spaces-of-continuous-functions/) post, the dual space of $C_b(T,\mathbb{R})$ can be identified with the space of regular bounded finitely additive measures on $T$, denoted by $\operatorname{rba}(T)$.

**My question**: Does $\int_T f \,\mathrm{d}\nu$ define a random variable (i.e. is it measurable) if $\nu\in \operatorname{rba}(T)$, and if yes, is it Gaussian?

I know this is true for Gaussian processes on $\mathbb{R}$ and integration against Lebesgue measure, but I am not sure how to prove it in this case. An idea was to write the integral as limit of integrals against simple functions and use that the almost sure limit of Gaussian variables is Gaussian, but that doesn't seem to work as easily as for Lebesgue integration.

Comment: I think I would find it surprising if it's not Borel-measurable or if its distribution is not Gaussian. $\qquad$

Comment: It looks to me like your idea will work. Based on the definition of the integral with respect to $\nu \in \mathrm{rba}(T)$ provided in the article, it seems like we should be able to write $$\int_T f_t(\omega) \, d \nu(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \sum_j f_{t_j}(\omega) \, \nu(B_j)$$ for every $\omega$, where the finitely many points $t_j$ and sets $B_j$ appearing in the sum are determined by $\epsilon$. Then the integral is an a.s. limit of measurable Gaussian random variables, hence is measurable and Gaussian, as you pointed out. Am I missing a problem with this argument?

Comment: @nahp Thanks for the comment! Yes, that was my initial idea too, but the sets $B_j$ (and thus the points $t_j$) depend, given $\varepsilon$, on the realisation $f(\omega)$ and thus on $\omega$, since they are defined by $B_j = f(\omega)^{-1}(A_j)$ (in the notation given in the article). Maybe this can be cleverly cirumvented somehow, but I don't see it.

Comment: Oh, that's right--I noted the dependence of the $t_j$'s and $B_j$'s on $\omega$ but hadn't noticed that this might "defeat" measurability. This is now just an idea, but perhaps you can argue that when $T$ is also compact, then you can choose *deterministic* $\delta$-nets $\{t_j\}$ of $T$ and express the integral as a limit of a sort of "Riemann sum," with the $\delta$-net taking the role of an interval partition. I think this might turn out to be the same as the definition of the integral given, because $t \mapsto f_t$ is a.s. uniformly continuous on $T$ thanks to compactness.